# structuremap using scan in objectfactory.initialize and also custom registry

Tags: model-view-controller, structuremap

I am learning to use structuremap and I've come into the following situation - 
I have been moving along fine using the following code in my global.asax -

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(registry => registry.Scan(x =>
                                           {
                                               x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                                               x.WithDefaultConventions(); 
                                               x.LookForRegistries();
                                           }));
```

now, i've come upon an instance where I have to create a registry and use that as well -

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(registry => registry.AddRegistry<MyRegistry>());
```

Can someone tell me how I can accomplish this?  Do I have to and create registries for everything now, or can I create one registry that will scan that I can then use with the other registry?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I jumped the gun with this - by calling x.LookForRegistries();, it does indeed discover my custom registry and everything seems to be working fine.

thanks